# Download a file and show it in downloads app or in notification in a cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

How do i make a file appear in the downloads app or in notification. Whenever a user clicks on the download in the app i want the file to get downloaded and show up in the default downloads app.

I could use the file transfer option of Cordova but it doesn't show up in the downloads app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use cordova InAppBrowser(cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).

```
window.open('http://www.myurl.com/file.pdf', '_system');
```

This will open the link in a system app. Which in most cases solves the problem.

Comment: I think a clarification is needed here (at least it would've saved me some time wondering what this comment really mean). You need to add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and then you can call window.open like this.